# What does the Customer is_active flag do?

Tags: customer, magento-1, customer-attribute

During a discussion today I was informed that the Customer is_active flag doesn't actually do anything.

This is a unique flag, like the customer email address, in that it's **not** an EAV attribute.  Instead, it is a column in the customer_entity table.

I tried setting the flag to 0 for a test customer, but am still able to login.  All other functionality seems to work normally.

Is this flag provided as a convenience to developers?  Is it intended for some future purpose?  What, if anything, does is_active do?

**Edit**: Here's a related stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617832/disable-customer-in-magento

Comment: I think it is from EE. There customer can be actived/deactivated as far as I remember

Comment: I have access to EE, but don't see that functionality anywhere.  Deleting them removes the row completely.

Comment: short grep over the EE-lite doesn't show anything. You are right. Then I would interpret it as stub for the functionality :-)

Comment: Same here as Toast mentioned: Don't see the functionality in EE Backend.

Comment: Ok can someone please post an answer? Toast, I think you did it, so answer your question and earn 25 rep :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a legacy field, derived from `Mage_Eav` and present as far back as v0.7.14800 (and perhaps earlier). As such, it by far predates the earliest version of EE.

Whether the value of this field is used or not is a matter of implementation  (such as it is for the `catalog_category` entity). I base this assertion on the fact that the `Mage_Eav` module does *not* provide any use of it as a base behavior for EAV entities.

Comment: in your opinion, is it safe to use this flag?  I'm working on a manual customer approval process that this seems designed for, but I'm hesitant to use if it isn't supported.

Comment: "support" in this case is what you build. I *would not* use this flag, as it may be used down the road. It would be better to add a namespaced attribute (eg. `toast_is_active`) to make use of.

Comment: Hi Ben @benmarks , in Magento 2 this legacy field in the _customer_entity_ table continues to exist.

Comment: why is it so filled with these plots ...

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this many years later, it just occurred to me that the `is_active` flag is probably present in any `[EAV]_entity` table because, at one time before the earliest releases, all entities were in a single `entity` table. When EAV entities were broken out into their own tables, this column went with them.

Best guess! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`