# Magento 2: Customer is_active field not working?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, bug

I'm trying to use this field that is in the table customer_entity but seems it's doing nothing. I change this value in the ddbb but the customer still can login, place orders, etc.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

I saw this similar question: [What does the Customer is_active flag do?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/what-does-the-customer-is-active-flag-do), but it's on Magento1, so I decided to open this for M2. Don't know if it's still the same or they changed something about this.

Comment: If you check in Customer module. It is not coming in use anywhere. Only just in installschema

Comment: So... well, I guess I'll have to implement this functionality, doesn't it?

Comment: yes correct .. you need to develop whole function and apply all check. You can also check for extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was solved on the comments.
Seems that if you want that functionality you must implement it by yourself.