# load customer object update issue in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, model, customer-session

I have used below code in my controller

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;

class editPost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  protected $_customer; 
  protected $customerFactory;
  public function __construct( 
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
  \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
  ) { 
   $this->_customer = $customer; 
   $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
   parent::__construct($context); 
  } 
public function execute()
{       
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false)) {
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false);

        $oldUser = $this->_getUser($userId);
        $user = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $user->load(null)
            ->setId($userId)
            ->setWebsiteId($oldUser->getWebsiteId());
        /* $user = $this->_customer->load()
                ->setId($userId)
                ->setWebsiteId($oldUser->getWebsiteId()); */

        $password = $oldUser->getPassword();

        $fields = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('customer_account');
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $defaultFields = array();
        foreach ($fields as $code=>$node) {
            $defaultFields[] = $code;
            if ((isset($node['create'])) && isset($data[$code])){
                $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
            }
        }
        $customerattr = $this->helperData->getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes();
        foreach ($customerattr as $_customerattr) {
            if (isset($data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]) && (!in_array($_customerattr, $defaultFields))) {
                $user->setData($_customerattr->getAttributeCode(), $data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]);
            }
        }

       // $errors = $user->validate();
        $errors = array();
        if (!is_array($errors)) {
            $errors = array();
        }
        if ($oldUser->getGroupId()) {
            $user->setGroupId($oldUser->getGroupId());
        }


        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_password')) {
            $currPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password');
            $newPass  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
            $confPass  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

            if (empty($currPass) || empty($newPass) || empty($confPass)) {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Password fields can\'t be empty.');
            }

            if ($newPass != $confPass) {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
            }

            $oldPass = $oldUser->getPasswordHash();
            $pos = strpos($oldPass, ':');
            if ($pos !== false) {
                list($_salt, $salt) = explode(':', $oldPass);
            } else {
                $salt = false;
            }

            if ($user->hashPassword($currPass, $salt) == $oldPass) {
                $user->setPassword($newPass);
            } else {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Invalid current password');
            }
        }

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $message) {                
                $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
            }
            return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/viewuser/', array('user_id' => $userId));
        }

        try {
            $user->save();
            $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__('User information was successfully saved.'));
            return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');
        }               
        catch (\Exception $e){
           $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e->getMessage());
           $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Can\'t save user'));
           return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');
        } 
    }
 }

private function _getUser($id)
{
    //$customerObj = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($id);
    $customerObj = $this->_customer->load($id);
    return $customerObj;

 }
}
```

Customer is not saving

Here is the code used on m1.

```
 if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false)) {
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false);
        $oldUser = $this->_getUser($userId);
        $user = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setId($userId)
            ->setWebsiteId($oldUser->getWebsiteId());

        $password = $oldUser->getPassword();




        $fields = Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account');
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $defaultFields = array();
        foreach ($fields as $code=>$node) {
            $defaultFields[] = $code;
            if ($node->is('update') && isset($data[$code])){
                $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
            }
        }
        $customerattr = Mage::helper('inkind_customer')->getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes();
        foreach ($customerattr as $_customerattr) {
            if (isset($data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]) && (!in_array($_customerattr, $defaultFields))) {
                $user->setData($_customerattr->getAttributeCode(), $data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]);
            }
        }

        $errors = $user->validate();
        if (!is_array($errors)) {
            $errors = array();
        }
        if ($oldUser->getGroupId()) {
            $user->setGroupId($oldUser->getGroupId());
        }


        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_password')) {
            $currPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password');
            $newPass  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
            $confPass  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

            if (empty($currPass) || empty($newPass) || empty($confPass)) {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Password fields can\'t be empty.');
            }

            if ($newPass != $confPass) {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
            }

            $oldPass = $oldUser->getPasswordHash();
            $pos = strpos($oldPass, ':');
            if ($pos !== false) {
                list($_salt, $salt) = explode(':', $oldPass);
            } else {
                $salt = false;
            }

            if ($user->hashPassword($currPass, $salt) == $oldPass) {
                $user->setPassword($newPass);
            } else {
                $errors[] = $this->__('Invalid current password');
            }
        }

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/view', array('user_id' => $userId));
            return $this;
        }

        try {
            $user->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('User information was successfully saved'));

            $this->_redirect('*/*/list');
            return;
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Can\'t save user'));
        }
    }
```

Where is mistake please anyone suggest me

Comment: Hi, you should try $this->_customer->load($userId) instead of setId($userId) in your execute function.

Comment: I am converting m1 code to m2, there it is used like that only, i am attaching that code also, please check my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use factory pattern that is bridge to connect incomplete object in magento 2.

use below code. I have changed customer model to factory pattern class. That is auto generated code concept of magento 2 you do not need to write any factory class. Magento managed by itself.

```
<?php 

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory as CustomerResourceFactory;

class editPost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_customer; 

    /**
     * @var CustomerResourceFactory
     */
    protected $customerResourceFactory;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        CustomerResourceFactory $customerResourceFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer
    ) { 
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->customerResourceFactory = $customerResourceFactory;
        parent::__construct($context); 
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false);
        $oldUser = $this->_getUser($userId);
        $oldUser->setEmail("email@domain.com"); //update attribute as per your need
        $oldUser->setFirstname("First Name");
        $oldUser->setLastname("Last name");

        $customerData = $oldUser->getDataModel();
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('attribute_code', 'attribute_value');
        $oldUser->updateData($customerData);

        $customerResource = $this->customerResourceFactory->create();
        $customerResource->saveAttribute($oldUser, 'attribute_code');


        $oldUser->save();
    }

    private function _getUser($id)
    {
        //$customerObj = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($id);
        $customerObj = $this->_customer->create();
        $customerObj->load($id);
        return $customerObj; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Used your code, error is removed but customer is not saving

Comment: @jafar updated code.  You need to set data which is mandatory required for customer like email, firstname, lastname

Comment: That will take from the old userId is it? we are taking from parameter

Comment: if there is already user available in database then what you want to do?

Comment: I am doing update, with the parameter coming from browser

Comment: you want to update existing customer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81287/discussion-between-jafar-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: Its not updating customer, i have custom attributes, so throwing error, how can i update customer with custom attributes?

Comment: @jafar updated code please check it. let me know if any error

Comment: hi Prashant, I didn't understand these two lines
 $customerResource = $this->customerResourceFactory->create();
 $customerResource->saveAttribute($oldUser, 'attribute_code');

Comment: This two line code save your custom attribute

Comment: $oldUser->setIsActive(0); is not working, i need to set is_active as false,How this can be done

Comment: That is your custom attribute right?

Comment: No. that is default attribute

Comment: please refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186901/magento-2-customer-is-active-field-not-working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81407/discussion-between-jafar-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: What to replace in customer_code in your code?

Comment: change attribute_code with your attribute name same as for value

Answer (score 3):

I think problem with your customer object

```
 $userId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id', false);
 $oldUser = $this->_getUser($userId);

    $user = $this->customerFactory->create();
    if($userId):
      $user->load($userId)->setWebsiteId($oldUser->getWebsiteId());      
    endif;
```