# What is the fastest way to get 'is_active' column value from 'customer_entity" table?

Tags: magento2, model

I'd like to ask for the fastest way to get the column value of 'is_active' from 'customer_entity' table. It could be using object_manager or something.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just so you know, is_active does nothing. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/what-does-the-customer-is-active-flag-do

Comment: @RomanKabanov Yeah im using the column for my custom feature

Comment: did you manage to do what you needed? I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 0):

Can you try fetching user using Collection?

```
// include customer collection
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection;

// inject in your class
public function __construct(
        Collection $collection
)


$customer = $this->collection->getItemById(6); // change this number please to match yours
var_dump($customer->getData('is_active'));
```

Comment: Its undefined method getData()