# Whats the use of the 'is_active' column in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

For what purpose does the 'is_active' column (in the 'customer_address_entity' table) exists?

I've tested this column by setting its value to 0,  and then checked if the address setted to 0 disappeared from the shipment checkout page, but it was still there.

Version Magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself the same question, but on *'customer_entity'* table (it has the same *'is_active'* flag) and same happens in the *'customer_address_entity'* it seems. The most useful resource I could find is [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/what-does-the-customer-is-active-flag-do) which explains that this flag could be a *legacy* column, not really used anywhere. Although this thread offers this probable explanation for m1, I think the same applies for m2:

> Coming back to this many years later, it just occurred to me that the is_active flag is probably present in any [EAV]_entity table because, at one time before the earliest releases, all entities were in a single entity table. When EAV entities were broken out into their own tables, this column went with them.

<sub>BenMark's update from 2020</sub>

So even this was probably the thing for m1, when they created m2, they didn't redesign everything and as far as EAV entities go, they simply carried the columns to m2 db as they were.

Comment: Thank you very much Diana.

Comment: you're most welcome!